# In Angular how can I communicate that all instances of a component have finished loading?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am currently working on two components & a service.
Essentially ComponentA communicates with the service to populate a map with the inputs of ComponentA.
ComponentB uses the fully populated map to load its view.

These components are essentially independent not a (child/parent of the other) but do share the same dependency injection which is the service.

The difficulty I'm having is that the number of ComponentAs in a view varies depending on the data being displayed so I do not know the number beforehand.

Essentially I'm looking for the following behavior:

1. When a page is loaded the service starts with a notReadyState for CompB.
2. X instances of CompA initialize and populate the map inside the service.
3. Once the X instances of CompA have loaded the service communicates that the map is ready to be used by CompB.

This might be weird/difficult to implement so I am also open to alternative suggestions. To how CompB can get a list of the CompA inputs.

Comment: How do you decide that all the instances of CompA have been initialized?

Comment: @Amer It's one of the things I'm trying to figure out initially I was thinking of in CompA's ngOnInit ping the service and CompB starts to render once the service has had a period of time with no new initializes from A but that seemed too hacky especially since I'd be using a timeout in code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ReplaySubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/replaysubject).

Implement it in your service.
When data are retrieved emit the value. And suscribe to it inside your componentB.

Answer (score 0):

if your componentAs and your componentB are at time (has the same parent) you get the data in parent and pass as `@Input()` the data to each componentA.

I imagine some like in your parent

```
<componentA *ngFor="let item of list;let i=index" [data]="data[i]|async">
</componentA>
<componentB [data]="allData">
</componentB>

//It's only one idea:

allData:any[]=[]
data:Observable[]=list.map(x=>this.service.getData(x.id).pipe(
   tap(x=>allData=allData.concat(x))
))
```